# How to disable promise manager in selenium-webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

As detailed in https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#Promises, `selenium-webdriver` uses an automatic promise manager to keep people from having to do repetitive promise chaining.

However, in some cases the assumption made by the promise manager, that successive calls should be chained is wrong, and it should be deactivated.

An example would be:

```
var isLoaded = function (browser) {
    var waitForJS = waitForElement(browser, By.css('body.js'));
    var waitForMobile = waitForElement(browser, By.css('#mobile_landing_page'));

    return Promise.any([waitForJS, waitForMobile]);
};
```

Here I want to create a generic function, that no matter whether it is on a mobile landing page or the desktop site waits until any of those two conditions is fulfilled.

The way the promise manager interprets it though is

```
var isLoaded = function (browser) {
    var waitForMobile = waitForElement(browser, By.css('#mobile_landing_page'));
    var waitForJS = waitForElement(browser, By.css('body.js')).then(function () {
        return waitForMobile;
    });

    return Promise.any([waitForJS, waitForMobile]);
};
```

This can obviously never resolve for the non-mobile case, since only one of those can be true at a time.

Is there a way to completely disable the promise manager and manually schedule all calls?

Here's the definition of `waitForElement`

```
var waitForElement = function (browser, element, timeout) {
    return browser.wait(until.elementLocated(element), timeout);
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to get what you want is simply to use a CSS selector that looks for one id *or* the other. The following example simulates a delayed loading. We are looking for an element with either `#foo` or `#bar`. So we use the selector `#foo, #bar`. In your case it would be `body.js, #mobile_landing_page`. Doing it this way is the most efficient way because it reduces the number of round-trips between your Selenium script and the browser.

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var By = webdriver.By;
var until = webdriver.until;
var firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');
var Promise = require('bluebird').Promise;

var browser = new firefox.Driver();

browser.get("http://www.example.com");

//
// Decide randomly what we are going to be looking for
//
// This math here is probably not something to be emulated if you need
// serious randomness (e.g. crypto).
//
var flip = Math.round(Math.random(0, 1));

var id = flip ? "foo": "bar";
console.log("We'll be simulating the delayed loading of an element with id", id);

var waitForElement = function (browser, element, timeout) {
    return browser.wait(until.elementLocated(element), timeout);
};

var isLoaded = function (browser) {
    return waitForElement(browser, By.css("#foo, #bar"));
};

// Simulate the delayed loading of the element we are going to look for.
browser.executeScript('\
var id = arguments[0];\
setTimeout(function () {\
  var el = document.createElement("div");\
  el.id = id;\
  document.body.appendChild(el);\
}, 1000);\
', id);

isLoaded(browser);
browser.quit();
```

Comment: This is exactly the perfect solution. It makes the code a lot simpler and works without problems. Thanks!
Sometimes things really are much easier than they seem.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but for anyone who google lands here **in/after 2017**, try this:

`Promise.any` is a bluebird construct. It returns the first thing to resolve.

If you want to wait for both, the correct method is `Promise.all`.

Try something like this:

```
var isLoaded = function (browser) {
    var waitForJS = waitForElement(browser, By.css('body.js'));
    var waitForMobile = waitForElement(browser, By.css('#mobile_landing_page'));

    return Promise.all([waitForJS, waitForMobile]);
};

// Then use like this:
isLoaded(browser)
.then((elemCheck) => {
  const hasBodyJsTag = elemCheck[0]
  const hasMobileTag = elemCheck[1]
  console.log('Elem Status:', elemCheck)
})
```